# Is there any way to convert the "import" code during webpack compilation

Tags: webpack

Is there a webpack plugin to do this?

during webpack complilation, I want to convert

```js
    import { a,b,c } from 'somefolder/index' // contains more sub modules that DO NOT want to be imported
```

to

```js
    import { a } from 'somefolder/a'
    import { b } from 'somefolder/b'
    import { c } from 'somefolder/c'
```

So, that I need not to include all sub modules under somefolder.

I tried to write a custom plugin to do this, and working `comlilation.hooks`, but don't know how to change the statement during the hook event

Comment: What difference would it make to you?

Comment: the package could be smaller, because there are many unused sub modules in `somefolder`

Comment: I guess webpack tackle that under the hood. It's called tree shaking